# Getting a thumbnail from a Bing News result using Bing News Search API

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-search

I am trying to get a thumbnail from an object that is returned using the Bing News Search API.  The only helpful attribute of the returned object that I can think of in this problem is the url. Is there any easy way of using this url to get the thumbnail for the article?

Answer (score 0):

Use the url Bing Search gives you back to make a curl call to the url and get the image from the page's OGP data. Several libraries are available in multiple programming languages to parse a webpage's OGP data.